# Native VIdeo player in android?

Tags: android, android-video-player

In android for an application if you need to open any link default we can launch it in **browser** instead of load it in `WebView`, similarly if i want to play the video , i have the video URL , how can i play it in default video player of android , instead of using `VideoView`.

If any one know means help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this to play video without using VideoView..

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = Uri.parse(Path to video file);
    intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But its open app chooser dialog if more then one video players are installed in the phone.
how to solve this issue?